# pass initial stdin across different commands

Tags: shell, stream, stdin

I am looking into writing a file that has its data coming through stdin, but manipulating it in such way that the first line of the stream is used to name the file and the 2nd+ lines are the file contents. so the command would be basically:

```
printf "foo\nbar" | tail +2 > $(head -1)
```

The problem with the above is that `head` receives its value from stdin but it doesn't seem to be passed onto `tail` resulting on an empty file `foo` being generated.

The same happens if I use:

```
printf "foo\nbar" | tail +2 /dev/stdin > $(head -1 /dev/stdin)
```

So I was wondering if there's any way to make use of the initial stdin in multiple commands, in a non-verbose manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a small shell script

```
#! /bin/sh
read filename
cat > $filename
```

Reading via shell has the advantage of unbuffered reading. Some utilities will read in buffered mode, which may consume some of the data beyond the first line.

Comment: That's really clever, thank you. If you don't mind, could you please expand on how this works from inside a shell script but not as an inline command like: `printf "foo\nbar" | read f; cat > "$f"` in which case, `f` is empty? I'm trying to get familiarised with [stdio buffering](https://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/) which may be one of the reasons as you mentioned? thanks again

Comment: To get your inline command to work, you need to group "read" and "cat" together. Otherwise, it execute two commands "printf | read" and then "cat" as separate command. Use: `printf "foo\nbar" | { read f ; cat >$f ; }`